# How to send respose after foreach in node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

In my foreach, I want to push data into an array and send the response to the client side.

I am using the below :

```
try {
    var allData = [];
    var venuesData = req.db.collection('venues').find({ "restaurantcompetitors": {$exists: true, $ne: null } }, {restaurantcompetitors:1});

    venuesData.forEach(function(data) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(allData, data);

        res.status(200).send({data: allData, code: 0});
    });

}
catch (error) {
    console.log('Error found in catch: ',error);
}
```

But I am getting an error "header already sent" because I'm sending inside the loop. But If I try to push data after the loop, it is not able to push...

Answer (score 3):

You realistically need to use a promise or use async/await

Read more here about async code and promises - https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098

More on async/await here - https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

```
try {
    var allData = [];
    var venuesData = await req.db.collection('venues').find({
        "restaurantcompetitors": {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: null
        }
    }, {
        restaurantcompetitors: 1
    });

    // This code won't run until the venuesData has resolved
    venuesData.forEach(function (data) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(allData, data);


    });
    //Need to send after you have done the loop
    res.status(200).send({
        data: allData,
        code: 0
    });

} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error found in catch: ', error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
      let i = 0 ;
      var allData = [];
      var venuesData = await req.db.collection('venues').find({ "restaurantcompetitors": 
            {$exists: true, $ne: null } }, {restaurantcompetitors:1});

      venuesData.forEach(function(data) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(allData, data);
            i++
      });
      if(i == venuesData.length){   
            res.status(200).send({data: allData, code: 0});
      }
   }catch (error) {
      console.log('Error found in catch: ',error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) module for this.

if you haven't installed **async** then install it by `npm install async --save`

First I am going to give you sample demo of static data how it works and then second is how you can implement in your code

First :

```
    var listNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    async.each(listNumbers, function(eachNumber, callback) {
        console.log("eachNumber:",eachNumber)
        callback();
    }, function(err) {

        if( err ) {
          console.log('something wrong');
        } else {
          console.log('everything works');
          res.json(listNumbers);
        }
   });
```

see first eachNumber will print 9 times then it will goes to everything works. same thing you can do in your code like as follows

Second :

```
    var allData = [];
    var venuesData = req.db.collection('venues').find({ "restaurantcompetitors": {$exists: true, $ne: null } }, {restaurantcompetitors:1});
    async.each(venuesData, function(data, callback) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(allData, data);
        callback();
    }, function(err) {
        if( err ) {
          console.log('something wrong');
          res.status(200).send({message:"something went wrong."});
        } else {
          console.log('everything works');
          res.status(200).send({data: allData, code: 0});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

High level hint: wrap your **foreach code** inside Promise and put any other promises in an array

and then make response

```
var promises = [];

// TODO: Create promise and push it in array i.e. promises.push()
// TODO: Any additional promise: promises.push(newpromise)

// TODO: Then call your code after all has completed
Promise.all(promises).then(() =>
   // put your response here 
   res.status(200).send({data: allData, code: 0});
);
```

How to create Promise: https://javascript.info/promise-basics

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
var allData = [];
var venues = req.db.collection('venues') // Get model object
venues.find({"restaurantcompetitors": {$exists: true, $ne: null } }, {restaurantcompetitors:1},function(err,venuesData){
    venuesData.forEach(function(data) {
       allData.push(data);  
    });
    res.status(200).send({data: allData, code: 0});
});
}
catch (error) {
console.log('Error found in catch: ',error);
}
```

Comment: Don't just slap some code as an answer without providing a description of what the actual solution is. That doesn't help anyone to learn.